# Nite 2 for Skeleton Tracking Kinect 2

Tags: ros, kinect, openni, skeleton, nite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everybody,

can someone tell me where I can download Nite 2 for Ubuntu 14.04?

the official homepage always shows an error message!

or can someone recommend something else for skeleton tracking with kinect 2 ?

many thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269032/nite-2-for-skeleton-tracking-kinect-2/) by [sawsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31405/sawsi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://bitbucket.org/kaorun55/openni-2.2/src/2f54272802bf/NITE%202.2%20%CE%B1/?at=master

---

Originally posted by [sawsi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31405/sawsi/) with karma: 38 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0